# Any methods to make prawns more "crunchy" (bite/tear off easily)

Tags: seafood

I notice that my prawns does not really get bite/tear off easily based on the way I prepare and cook my prawns - I tear off the shell, put them on a bowl. When ready to cook, I just thrown them together with some lean meat (cow / pig) and cook. After cooking, I put them into noodles/spaghetti and cook once more.

I suspect that there are 2 shells for prawns but I can't seems to get the prawns more "crunchy" such a way that they can be bitten / tear off easily without using oil and flour.

Appreciate any suggestions offer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How are you cooking the meat? Are you then boiling it along with the pasta? (Why are you cooking it twice?) What do you mean that prawns have two shells? Are you eating their shells? And honestly, what do you mean by crunchy? (I've never had trouble biting through shrimp.)

Comment: Are you trying to get your prawns to be firm on the outside but easily tear-away from the tail once you bite through?  Are your prawns tough and chewy?

Comment: @Jefromi, Hi Jefromi, please refer to Jacob who had described my situation.

Comment: @JacobG, Thanks for describing my situation. I believe that you also had such situation before. May I ask you to edit my question to improve it. Thanks, yes, my prawns are chewy and does not tear away easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chewy or rubbery prawns are a good sign that you've overcooked them. As with other seafood, they don't take kindly to being overcooked. You should probably cook them separately, just enough, and then mix them into whatever you're eating them with.

You can use whatever cooking method you like; common ones include boiling, steaming, and stir-frying. Whatever you do, just make sure you don't do too much of it. Any cooking beyond done makes them worse.

Since you seem to prefer boiling: as soon as they're done, you should dump them into a colander and run cold water over them immediately afterward to stop them from cooking further. Cooking times vary depending on size; small shrimp take only a few minutes, while very large ones might take 5-10. They'll probably be pink and some will be starting to float; to tell for sure whether they're cooked you can cut one in half and make sure it's opaque all the way through.

Comment: This is probably the issue - shrimp takes far less time to cook than meat, even lean meat, so if you're cooking until the meat is done your shrimp will be overcooked and rubbery.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking about is that juicey snap you get with some prawns at seafood places.  The secret is to take your peeled prawns and soak them for 30 minutes or so in salted ice water.  Go for sea water like saltiness or slightly better.  When you cook them up (don't over cook!) you'll notice a huge difference.